# Position cursor at start/end of Word document

Tags: .net, interop, ms-word, mergefield

We are manipulating our Word 2007 documents from .Net using Word Interop. Mostly doing stuff with fields as in:

```
For Each f In d.Fields
    f.Select()
    //do stuff with fields here            
Next
```

This leaves the last field in the document selected.

So, for the sake of neatness we would like to position the cursor at the **end** of the document (or even the **start** would be OK).

Googling for the answer doesn't throw up much ... the nearest I can get seems to be suggesting we need to involve ourselves with ranges or bookmarks. There's a `GoTo` method for the `Document` object but none of the `WdGoToItem` options it offers are useful.

Isn't there a simple way to just send the cursor to the end (or start) of document?

**Edit**

Part of my problem was I didn't like leaving the last field selected. Have now realised that I can do

```
f.Unlink
```

to remove the `mergefield` and just leave the field text there as plain text. Which is neater, whether or not we also reposition the cursor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Alexander Kojevnikov: Thanks for your help because you put me on the right track. However I found I had to apply the .GoTo to the Word Selection object, not the Document. As in:

```
    Dim what As Object = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine
    Dim which As Object = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast

    //below line had no effect
    //d.GoTo(what, which, Nothing, Nothing)

    w.Selection.GoTo(what, which, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: On my VisualStudio 2013 implementation this places the cursor at the **start** of the last line, not quite the end of the document.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator VS 2013 or Office 2013? I am seeing some different behavior moving from Office 2010 (v14) to Office 2013 (v15). Both of them using the VS 2010 IDE, however

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis Definitely VS2013. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21924860/1168342) for a solution that worked for me.

Comment: VS2013 is an IDE. How on earth does that have any impact? What .NET runtime are you using? What version of VSTO? What version of Office?

Answer (score 9):

This is how it looks in C#:

```
object missing = Missing.Value;
object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
object which = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;
doc.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref missing, ref missing);
```

I guess it will be even easier in VB.Net as it supports optional parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'm using the same environment as you, but to go to the **start** or **end** of the document here's what works for me:

```
Private Sub moveCursorToStartOfDocument()
    w.Selection.HomeKey(WdUnits.wdStory, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub moveCursorToEndOfDocument()
    w.Selection.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I use unit Word_TLB in Delphi with Appliction object-  Word.Application

as following:

```
aWordDoc.Application.Selection.EndKey(wdStory,wdMove);
```

**generally end of word document is**:

```
Selection.EndKey( WdUnits.wdStory, WdMovementType.wdMove)
```

When I use

```
Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast, Nothing, Nothing);
Selection.InsertFile('documnet.docx');
```

new content was insert before last line.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to figure out an outline for the actual code is to record a macro in Word for that specific action. Then you can modify the generated code to suit different syntax(s) of VB, VB.NET, C# etc.

The code snippet below demonstrates the usage for a VB.NET application:

```
Imports wordNmSpace = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
' Create an object for the application instance
objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

' Create a reference of the selection object within Word
objSelection = objWord.Selection

' Now comes the part where you move selection position to the end of document
objSelection.endof(wordNmSpace.WdUnits.wdStory, wordNmSpace.WdMovementType.wdMove)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To change cursor position at the end of the current document in a C# Word Add-In VSTO :

```
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.End-1,
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.End-1).Select();
```

See [How to: Programmatically Define and Select Ranges in Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int lNumberOfPages = 
  _WordDoc.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);

WordApp.Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage,WordApp.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast, lNumberOfPages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the predefined bookmark:

```
EndOfDoc oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range
```

Other predefined bookmarks:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Para").Copy "currpara"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/predefined-bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

for net office:

```
mydoc.Range(GlobalClass.mydoc.Content.End-1 , mydoc.Content.End - 1).Select();
```