# Move my cursor to the end of the Text in MsWord using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

This question might sound very simple but I am unable to find any Solution for it.What I am trying to do is to Move my Cursor Positon in MsWord to the end of the text.My code is as follows

```
  object StartPos = 0;
  object Endpos = 1;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng= oDoc.Range(ref StartPos, ref Endpos);
  rng.Text = "This is first line Word from C#";
```

The output is

**I** This is first line Word from C#

however i want something like this

This is first line Word from C# **I**

Thanks All

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well thank you all for your response I seem to have figured out a simple Solution.I tried to modify Hassan's Solution.There might be a much easier approach but as of now I have Found This

```
object NewEndPos = rng.StoryLength-1;
        rng = oDoc.Range(ref NewEndPos, ref NewEndPos);
        rng.Select();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It's the same as pressing Ctrl-Shift-End. Note that `word` is the word application, not the document. It's assumed that the correct active document is already selected.

```
word.Selection.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rng= oDoc.Range(ref Endpos, ref Endpos);
rng.Select();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Similar question - Position cursor at start/end of Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591682/position-cursor-at-start-end-of-word-document)

That answer goes into more detail about the `which` and the `what`. The answers are kind of mashed up between c# and vb so I include *yet another answer* here, that uses a slightly different method of going to the last part of the document.

My two cents:

```
//vb does this kind of thing for them
//but in c# we need an object we can pretend is null
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

//Start Word and create a new document.
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc; //whenever i read this i think 'hodor'
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
  ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

object StartPos = 0;
object Endpos = 1;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = oDoc.Range(ref StartPos, ref Endpos);
rng.Text = "This is first line Word from C#";

//object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
//I couldn't get wdGoToLine to work but wdGoToPercent was happy
object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPercent;
object which = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;

oWord.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, oMissing, oMissing);
```

This method is slightly different in that it doesn't tell word to move the cursor to the last line, but the last *percentage* of the document, which I will have to assume is 100. That would be the end of the line in a one-line document, but if the cursor is on the first line (at the beginning) and we tell Word to goto the last line, nothing happens: we are already there, at the *beginning* of the *last line*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
oDoc.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is that access to Word documents and find the current range. Then you have to find the current position of the cursor. You need to use this code:

```
var selection = Document.Application.Resource.Range;
object position = selection.Resource.StoryLength - 1;
var range = Document.Range(ref position, ref position);
range.Select();
```

Now, the cursor is at the end of its position.