# How do I insert a tab character into a Word document with Word Interop?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

The question says it all.  I am attempting to insert a tab character into my Word document which is generated with Word interop.  The usual `\t` does not work.

I literally just want to insert some text (tab) text (tab) text; so I am not talking about tab indents at the beginning of a line, but within text itself.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not affiliated in any way, but I've had better luck with the Spire.Doc Nuget package (there's a free version) than I ever had with Word Interop. You might want to look into that, if your question goes unsolved. I'm not sure if it'll do it or not, but I think it should be able to.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm having a look; looks good so far.

Comment: Yep. I think there are a few things that the free version *doesn't* do, and it's been a little while since I did anything with it, but I know I never encountered a need for any of them, at least with what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
wordApp.oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("Your custom text");
WordApp.oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("\t");
wordApp.oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("Your next custom text");
WordApp.oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("\t");
```

or if you just want to go to the end of the document:

```
object missing = Missing.Value;
object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
object which = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;
doc.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref missing, ref missing);
```

credits to [Alexander Kojevnikov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591757/2618541)

Comment: This might work, but how do I get the selection to become the very end of the document?