# Getting to the top of a word document in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I am opening a word document from my VB windows forms application then adding text from several text boxes. I need this text to go to very beginning of the document every time rather than at the very end. Have searched online for hours and cannot seem to find a solution to this! I have managed to find `WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst` but don't know what to do with it. Any guidance would be a help.

```
        Dim oWordApp As New Word.Application
    oWordApp.Visible = True
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\christopherm\Desktop\TestBoard.htm")
    oDoc = oWordApp.ActiveDocument

    Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph, oPara2 As Word.Paragraph
    Dim oPara3 As Word.Paragraph, oPara4 As Word.Paragraph
    Dim oBeginning As Object = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst

    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Text = "Heading 1234" & vbCrLf
    oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0
    oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = True
    oPara1.Range.Font.Size = 12
    oPara1.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

Comment: Here's an [answer showing how to use WdGoToDirection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1593245/6664878)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a `Range` object that points to the beginning of the document. You can get that by getting the entire range of the document and then going to the beginning of that range:

```
Dim rng as Range = ActiveDocument.Range
rng.Collapse ' collapses the range to the beginning

rng.Text = "Heading 1234" & vbCrLf

Dim para1 as Paragraph = rng.Paragraphs(1)
para1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0
' continue here ...
```

If you instead want to use the `Document.Paragraphs.Add` method to insert a new paragraph at the beginning of the document, you need to pass a range object pointing to that location:

```
Dim rng As Range = ActiveDocument.Range
rng.Collapse ' range object at the beginning of the document

' pass the range where the paragraph shall be inserted
Dim para1 as Paragraph = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add(rng)
```

Comment: So this does get me to the beginning of the document, but any paragraphs I add using para1.text go straight to the bottom?

Comment: @ChrisMcCarthy: Please see my update for clarification.

Comment: Fantastic! With a few adjustments this does exactly what I need it to! Thanks Dirk. Just finishing up some other work, will post full code once it's done for others to use if needed.

Comment: @ChrisMcCarthy: If you found the answer helpful, please upvote. If it solved your question, mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Will do both. One final question, is it possible to add a hyperlink via para1.Range.text =

Comment: Never mind, cracked it. para1.Range.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, "Link", , , "Text to show")